# C2DM Broadcast receiver stops being called after some time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm

I have a working broadcast receiver for C2DM, which normally works perfectly, but in some cases in the field, it just stops being invoked by the system. My question is:

Under what circumstances would Android suddenly stop sending intents to a particular application, even if the app is currently running?

Given that it works the majority of the time, I'm trying to figure out if there's some way for the broadcast receiver to "go bad" or the process be marked bad etc. I have verified that Google is happy with the C2DM (i.e. it's not rate-limited due to quota or anything like that).

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same problem and what helps me is toggling wifi on and off, when it reconnects it starts receiving again. For me this is only the case when using C2DM, not tested with other broadcastreceivers. I know that this is not really an exact answer to the problem.

There also happens to be a problem with C2DM not working very good over wifi. So are you using your wifi connection or mobile-internet? Try only using your mobile internet for a while and see if the receiver still stops receiving.

Let me know if one of these tips got you any further!

Dino

Answer (score 0):

just change one line in manifest.

receiver  android:name=".MyBoardCastReceiver"  android:enabled="true"